# Angular and Bootrap 4: The grid is destroyed with ngFor

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get the grid 2 columns for list of image

With this code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://...225636.png"
            style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://...225636.png"
            style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://...225636.png"
            style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
    </div>
</div>
```

=> The grid display nicely with 2 columns

But when I try to use ngFor to create the grid:

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let asset of assets">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="http://...225636.png"
                style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

=> The 2 columns grid is not displayed, instead displayed one column list

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .col must be directly under the .row, just like in the first example. I'm not sure why you introduced an additional div here.

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let asset of assets" class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://...225636.png"
             style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let asset of assets">
            <img src="http://...225636.png"
                style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, use `ng-container` for a disappearing "element".

```
<div class="row">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let asset of assets">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="http://...225636.png"
                style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

It's most useful when you can't introduce an intermediate element, like between a `<ul>` and its `<li>` direct children.